# Есть ли у имени массива, когда оно используется как указатель, адрес в памяти?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Имя массива может **может** служить указателем. Можно проверить, какой размер занимает указатель( по сути имя массива ). cout << sizeof(&arr) << endl; или cout << sizeof(arr+0) << endl; Но раз указатель занимает 4 или 8 байт ( в зависимости от конфигурации x64 или x84 ), то у него должен появляться какой-то адрес, у самого указателя. **Вопрос**: как получить этот адрес? Этот адрес должен же быть отличным от адресов элементов массива, т.к. это указатель, если проводить аналогию. Или для массива адрес указателя( его имени ) вывести на экран нельзя??? Но он же есть, раз занимает какое-то место в памяти. Вопрос именно по c++.

Comment: Указатель на указатель работает так же, как указатель, например, на int. Если вы записали указатель в память, можете получить его адрес через операцию &.

Comment: Не стоит называть имя переменной именем массива. В определенных контекстах массив может быть неявно преобразован в указатель на первый элемент. Этот указатель будет являться новым временным объектом. С/C++ не допускают взятие адреса у временных объектов. Однако никто не мешает вам сохранить этот временный указатель в переменную и проверить ее адрес.

Comment: @user7860670 Про временный указатель хорошо сказано, но как получить адрес хотя бы временного, мне бы фрагмент кода, если не сложно. И сколько вообще указатель этот будет жить? Поменяется ли адрес потом? Я понимаю, что вопрос странный и может не нужный.

Comment: Я же написал, **С/C++ не допускают взятие адреса у временных объектов. Однако никто не мешает вам сохранить этот временный указатель в переменную и проверить ее адрес.**

Comment: Понимаете, это как вот написали вы литерал - скажем, `5` или там `3.1415926`. Это значение `int` (`double`). Но раз такое значение занимает 4 или 8 байт, то у него должен быть какой-то адрес? Какой адрес у значения `5`? Вот примерно так и вы спрашиваете...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указатель, получающийся из массива неявным преобразованием, вычисляется на месте. До преобразования он не существует и нигде не хранится.

Это <s>временный объект</s>  [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), поэтому он даже объектом не считается, и у него нет адреса. Точно так же, как у (не строковых) литералов вроде `42`.

С prvalue можно сделать две вещи:

- Им можно инициализировать объект (т. е. указатель), например так: `int a[42]; int *b = a;`. Тогда адрес `a` напрямую записывается в `b`, и никакой временный указатель не создается.
- Его можно материализовать ([temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization)) во временный объект, в xvalue.

Компилятор не дает напрямую взять адрес xvalue, но это искусственное ограничение. Можно сделать rvalue-ссылку на него, и взять адрес у ссылки:

```
#include <iostream>

int **foo(int *&&ptr) {return &ptr;}

int main()
{
    int a[42];
    std::cout << a << '\n';
    std::cout << foo(a) << '\n';
}
```

Я получил `0x7fff4ac52380` `0x7fff4ac52378`, т. е. временный указатель оказался на стеке рядом с массивом.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно хороший ответ, даже что-то излишне для меня, но буду знать, что такое есть. Но у меня остался вопрос. Я не до конца понимаю, как работает эта функция. А именно зачем здесь двойной указатель ** и как он тут отрабатывает и почему два & в *&&ptr.  С *& сталкивался, а с таким ещё нет.

Comment: @kosmp Угу, С++ сложный стал, более простое объяснение было бы неправильным. *"зачем здесь двойной указатель **"* Ну, мы же хотим адрес указателя. Просто указатель на int - одна звездочка, указатель на указатель - две. *"почему два &"* Это называется rvalue-ссылка. Чем-то похоже на обычную ссылку, но в комментариях быстро не объяснить. В принципе тут можно было бы написать `int *const &ptr`, тоже бы сработало.

Comment: С int *const &ptr работал.  А благодаря ** мы можем получить адрес или как? Есть краткое объяснение какое-то? А то в комментах тут много писанины будет.

Comment: @kosmp Нуу, я уже попробовал коротко объяснить, не знаю как еще. `int **` - это "указатель на указатель на int". Вы же хотите адрес указателя (указатель на указатель), а не адрес какого-то элемента массива.

Comment: Ага. Потом поподробнее узнаю про **  Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Можете всё-таки как-нибудь попробывать объяснить, почему тип функции именно int** и почему именно *&&? И я попробывал использовать `int *const &ptr, тоже бы сработало.` , но оно не сработало. Знаю, как работают двойные указатели, но тут как-то всё равно не сходится.

Comment: И раз это временный объект, то почему всё-таки удаётся получить адрес пускай и таким непростым способом?

Comment: @Kosmp *"оно не сработало"* Недосмотрел, надо еще возвращаемый тип на `int *const *` заменить. *"почему тип функции именно `int**`"* Потому вы хотите получить указатель на указатель (адрес указателя). Заметьте, что слово указатель написано два раза - поэтому две звездочки. *"почему именно `*&&`"* Неконстантные lvalue-ссылки (т.е. которые с одним амперсандом) нельзя инициализровать rvalue (грубо говоря, временными объектами. Константные - можно, поэтому `int *const &ptr` работает. Rvalue-ссылки, (два амперсанда) исходя из названия, тоже можно, поэтому `&&` работает.

Comment: Зачем в принципе нужны rvalue-ссылки просто так в комментах не объяснить. Гуглите move semantics.

Comment: Если это неочевидно, `&&` имеют особое значение. Это не "ссылка на ссылку". В отличие от `**`, которые никакого особого значения не имеют.

Comment: *"раз это временный объект, то почему всё-таки удаётся получить адрес"* Потому что у них есть адрес. Интереснее другое, почему `&` на них не работает. Ответ - это произвольное ограничение, чтобы случайно себе ногу не отстрелить.

Comment: Но возвращаем то мы `return &ptr;` т.е. адрес, где лежит указатель на указатель, а не значение указателя на указатель ( или, другими словами, не адрес, по которому лежит наш временный первый указатель)

Comment: @Kosmp Нет, почему. *"адрес, по которому лежит наш временный первый указатель"* Именно его и возвращаем.

Comment: Я просто провёл аналогию с обычной переменной, на которую если сделать указатель на указатель и вывести вот так вот &ptr, то это адрес, где лежит указатель на указатель, а не где лежит указатель

Comment: @Kosmp А где мы применяем `&` к указателю на указатель? `ptr` - ссылка не указатель на `int`.

Comment: Я думал, что здесь `return &ptr;` , но тут важна ещё эта запись `int *&&ptr`, которую как-то сложно понять. Вот  `int *&ptr` понятно, это тот же указатель, что и в main. Можно даже изменить адрес, на что указывает. Т.е. одно и то же. А `int *&&ptr` это что-то другое. Просто ** же даже говорят, что мы возвращаем адрес указателя на указатель

Comment: @Kosmp Rvalue-ссылки - они такие же, как lvalue-ссылки. Разница только в том, чем их можно инициализировать (rvalue или lvalue). Другой разницы нет.

Comment: Еще раз, `&&` это не "ссылка на ссылку". У двух амперсандов особое значение. А со звездочками не так, их может быть сколько угодно, и у двух звездочек рядом нет какого-то скрытого смысла. Указатели на указатели ничем принципиально не отличаются от указателей на не-указатели.

Comment: Почему при альтернативной записи нужен const?? `int *const *`   `int *const &ptr`

Comment: @Kosmp В ссылке он нужен потому, что как я уже сказал, неконстантные lvalue-ссылки нельзя инициализровать rvalue, а константные можно. А константность возвращаемого указателя просто должна совпадать с константностью, написанной в параметре (или быть более строгой).